# WCF returned System.IO.Stream garbled

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, iis-6

I'm wrapping an existing ASMX webservice with a WCF interface as a transition phase in my software project to save time. This works well except for one function which returns a System.String.

The original ASMX service returned either text or XML depending on the parameters given. This was not a problem in ASMX. In WCF the returned value, if XML, is escaped like: `&lt;gml&gt;` where it should be `<gml>`. Please see the underneath SOAP.

**Request**

```
POST http://someuri.org/WebServices/Utils.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://www.someuri.org/IUtils/Function
Content-Length: 283
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
Host: foo.bar.org
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Function xmlns="http://www.someri.org/">
            <type>...</type>
            <input1>...</input1>
            <input2>...</input2>
            <input3>true</input3>
        </Function >
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 11:40:01 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2070

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <FunctionResponse xmlns="http://www.crotec.nl/">   
            <FunctionResult>&lt;gml&gt;data&lt;/gml&gt;</FunctionResult>
        </FunctionResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Some googling brought me to returning a System.IO.Stream object.

```
string result = DoStuff(arg1, arg2, arg3);            
byte[] bin = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
return new System.IO.MemoryStream(bin);
```

This works to a point.

```
string result =  "02010415DBD800D7E17577787A626978";
byte[] bin = {48,50,48,49,48,52,49,53,68,66,68,56,48,48,68,55,69,49,55,53,55,55,55,56,55,65,54,50,54,57,55,56};
```

The returned result in the SOAP message is however:

```
MDIwMTA0MTVEQkQ4MDBEN0UxNzU3Nzc4N0E2MjY5Nzg=
```

So the resulting output is garbled (again, I think, caused by the message encoding(?))

The method is attr's with an OperationContract and the service is hosted in IIS6 with the following ABC:

```
<service name="WebServices.BeheerUtils" behaviorConfiguration="Services.ServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebServices.IUtils"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

Any ideas why the output is garbled or how to prevent the HTML encoding?

**Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
System.IO.Stream Function(string type, string input1, string input2, string input3);
```

**Implementation**

```
public new System.IO.Stream Function(string type, string input1, string input2, string input3)
{
    // Call the old ASMX method
    string result = DoStuff(type, input1, input2, input3, true);

    byte[] bin = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(bin);
}
```

Comment: The text `MDIwMTA0MTVEQkQ4MDBEN0UxNzU3Nzc4N0E2MjY5Nzg=` is base64 encoded value of `02010415DBD800D7E17577787A626978`.

Comment: Could you post details on your WCF service interface - at least method definition. I don't really understand why using asmx you could return either string or xml and using WCF you're unable to do it (isn't xml just a string?).

Comment: Thanks for the update, but could you answer my second question - why can't you just return string?

Comment: Because the DoStuff() method also can return XML data. This XML string in the variable may look like "<gml>data</gml>", but in the SOAP envelope returned it looks like "&lt;gml&gt;data&lt;/gml&gt;". This is the actual problem I wish to solve. Do you know how to change the encoding of the Stream? From 64 bits to 8?

Comment: Why are you checking the SOAP message? Do you have to handle it at such a low level? WCF have to encode special XML characters in order to send it in XML message - that's a standard and expected behavior.

Comment: Btw, check your request - and set input1 to <gml>data</gml> - you will see it is encoded exactly like in the response.

Comment: I've update my answer - if you're manually parsing the SOAP response I guess you're deserializing it's content with XMLSerializer. According to my test it should give correct result.

Comment: Yes I see, only I am using classic ASP for parsing the responses. Therefore it is desirable to do as much of the processing as possible in C#. It is perfectly possible to return an XML literal in the SOAP envelope (see my update). I'd only hope it'll be possible to do this without wrapping it in yet other XML element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fiddled around with some return types and this is what I can up with:

```
string result = DoStuff(type, input1, input2, input3, true);

XDocument d = new XDocument();
XDocument basis = new XDocument(new XElement("result"));

// Load the result into a XDocument, add the result as a value of the wrapper element if the format is invalid    
try
{
    d = XDocument.Parse(result);
    basis.Root.Add(d.Root);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    basis.Root.Value = result;
}    

// Return the XElement
return basis.Root;
```

I basically wrap all responses in a new Root element. This gives me literal XML in the SOAP enveloped instead of 'html encoded'. Though it does what I need, I find it awkward. However I found no other solution fitting my need so I present this as the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot agree with this statement:

> This was not a problem in ASMX. In WCF the returned value, if XML, is
>   escaped like: `&lt;gml&gt;` where it should be `<gml>`.

I created a service with method:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetXml(string str);

public string GetXml(string str)
{
    return "<gml>" + str + "</gml>";
}
```

And then I call the service with generated WCF Client:

```
var client = new MyWcfServiceClient();
var result = client.GetXml("test");
```

The result is:

```
<gml>test</gml>
```

**UPDATE**

Just to ensure you that it's a standard way for xml to behave please perform the following test and check the value of `respone.FunctionResult`:

```
public class FunctionResponse
{
    public string FunctionResult { get; set; }
}

public void Test()
{
    var serialized = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<FunctionResponse>   
    <FunctionResult>&lt;gml&gt;data&lt;/gml&gt;</FunctionResult>
</FunctionResponse>";
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FunctionResponse));
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(serialized))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            var response = ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);                    
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: I assure you, I am not lying. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Nebula: I'm not saying you're lying :) I'm saying that if you generate / create the wcf client you should get correct result.

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. Actually the service is consumed by a classic ASP website. I guess this is where a gap exists. We have to write all the messages by hand so there is no framework I can use.

Comment: @Nebula: what do you mean by classic ASP? Adding Web Reference (not Service Refence) also works fine.

Comment: I hope I understand your question right. Classic ASP is the technology before ASP.Net. There you cannot add references to webservices simply because it is not natively supported as opposed to ASP.Net. Does my updated question give you inspiration as to solve this problem without adding an additional XML element?

Comment: @Nebula: I hoped that by classic you mean asp.net not asp.net mvc ;) I have no experience with classic asp but I suppose there is a decent XML parser for it, that should understand that special characters were encoded. Unfortunately, I don't think I will be able to help you more with this issue.

Comment: @empi Classic ASP is before ASP.NET.

Comment: @empi Alas, very little out-of-the-box functions in ASP Classic afaik. Anyhow, the problem has a acceptable workaround now. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

If your function returns a string, then it's normal that it should be encoded.

You could try declaring your function to return an `XmlNode` instead of a string.

Comment: Would an XmlNode be able to contain plain text as weel? So with no parent element?

Comment: Adding to my first response; I don't necessarily think it is normal for it to be escaped. At least not without giving me an option to disable this escaping. Maybe there is such an option? In that case I'd like to learn as how to do this for I am unable to obtain this as of yet.

Comment: @Nebula, I don't know of an option to disable escaping.  A string inside a SOAP message needs to be escaped, but this should be transparent to the caller - any XML API that extracts the contents of the node will automatically unescape the string.

Comment: Yeah I'd expected that too. The XML API for ASP Classic does not seem to do that for us however (my colleague writes this, I'm not particularly well trained in VBS)

Answer (score 0):

Use basicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding.